# Installation errors on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to get fullcalendar js up and running. All the files are uploaded. Things are in place as far as the instructions I found.

This is what is included in my page head:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='/fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>

<link href='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
```

My site currently uses and loads jQuery elsewhere, which is why it is not listed above.

This is what's on my page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'Ao87hfiualhisitBO_eBlaJbwtuga13IM',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'kljfho2938h98fah@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
       (anonymous function) @ fullcalendar.min.js:6
       (anonymous function) @ fullcalendar.min.js:6
gcal.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applyAll' of undefined
       (anonymous function) @ gcal.js:22
       (anonymous function) @ gcal.js:15
       (anonymous function) @ gcal.js:17
(index):328 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
     (anonymous function) @ (index):328
```

Any ideas or pointers? Any additional info that would be helpful?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `moment.js` before `fullcalendar.js`

```
<script src='/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='/fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<link href='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
```

> jQuery and Moment must be loaded before FullCalendar's JavaScript.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of all errors except for the '$ is not a function'  for the line  '$(document).ready(function() {'.

Comment: oh, fixed it. Had to replace $ with 'jQuery.'  Calendar still not showing up, but I'll keep tinkering with it. No errors at least